# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource - Ionic 3 and Laravel

Tags: laravel, cors, ionic3

I am trying to connect my application with a backend server in Laravel

I have an interceptor that adds the headers in the request:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
console.log('----------------- SESSION -----------------');
console.log(this.session.token);

this.token = this.session.token;
const headers = this.buildRequestHeaders();
const authRequest = req.clone({
  setHeaders: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'false',
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET",
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.token}`
  }
});

return next.handle(authRequest);
```

}

On the server I have a middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Helpers\JsonResponseHelper;
use Closure;
use JWTAuth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken;

class JwtCheck extends GetUserFromToken
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
        header('Access-Control-Request-Headers', 'Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, Accept');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    if (strpos($request->headers->get("Authorization"), "Bearer ") === false) {
        $request->headers->set("Authorization", "Bearer " . $request->headers->get("Authorization"));
    }

    if (!$token = $this->auth->setRequest($request)->getToken()) {
        $data['errors'] = trans('auth.failed');
        $message = trans('auth.failed');
        return JsonResponseHelper::dataResponse(trans('messages.error'), $data, true, 401, $message);
    }
    try {
        //$user = $this->auth->authenticate($token);
        $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate($token);
    } catch (TokenExpiredException $e) {
        $data['errors'] = trans('messages.token-expired');
        $message = trans('messages.token-expired');
        return JsonResponseHelper::dataResponse(trans('messages.error'), $data, true, 401, $message);
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        $data['errors'] = $e->getMessage();
        $message = trans('messages.error');
        return JsonResponseHelper::dataResponse(trans('messages.error'), $data, true, 401, $message);
    } catch (TokenInvalidException $e) {
        $data['errors'] = $e->getMessage();
        $message = trans('messages.error');
        return JsonResponseHelper::dataResponse(trans('messages.error'), $data, true, 401, $message);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $data['errors'] = $e->getMessage();
        $message = trans('messages.error');
        return JsonResponseHelper::dataResponse(trans('messages.error'), $data, true, 401, $message);
    }
    if (!$user) {
        $data['errors'] = trans('auth.failed');
        $message = trans('auth.failed');
        return JsonResponseHelper::dataResponse(trans('messages.error'), $data, true, 401, $message);
    }
    $request->merge(array("user" => $user));
    $request->merge(array("token" => $token));

    return $next($request);
```

Here's my problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CG9Tq.png

This is the request sent to the server. Apparently my Access-Control-Allow-Originis adding inside the Request headers:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXN0L.png

Comment: you'll need to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` at your server.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the error states `Response to Pre-flight request doesn't pass the control check`, At this control check the server tells the browser or client, that it is allowed to make request to it. This Request is fired before your original the original request. You are setting headers in the controller, the request gets rejected before it reaches the controller,

Create a middleware named Cors and in its handle method:

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
          ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
          ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS')
          ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'content-type, authorization, x-requested-with');
    }
```

and in **Kernel.php** pass your newly created middleware.

```
 protected $middleware = [ 
    \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class, 
];
```

you don't need to pass `access-control` headers in your ionic client, these are generated by your server during preflight, to let the client know what is allowed by the server.
Set headers in your ionic like,

```
setHeaders: {
   Accept: `application/json`,
  'Content-Type': `application/json`,
   Authorization: `Bearer ${this.token}`
   }
```

Also JWT-Auth comes with a inbuilt middleware to check if the request is by an authenticated entity, simply use it on your protected routes

```
jwt.auth = \Tymon\JWTAuth\Middlware\GetUserFromToken::class
```

Comment: Did not work. I think the problem is in IONIC, because if I do not add the token in the request, the server accepts the request

Comment: are you unable to use authorization as an header? `"Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Authorization",`

Comment: I'm just getting put `Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,content-type`.But I need  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Comment: is it happening only on requests that are without token or on all requests?

Comment: only when I make changes to the request header by my interceptor

Comment: you should also move your exception handling to `App\Exceptions\Handler.php class`

Comment: Are you using Ionic or Angular for your http requests?